# Drag and drop reset for multiple images

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to create a reset button for the multiple draggable images I have in multiple arrays so that they return to their original places. I've looked at updating the center of each image to the original location and also looked into trying to implement viewDidLoad. Neither of these worked great for me and I'm not sure if theres a better way. Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, a.) you're using UIImageView (or some subclass of); b.) you don't have Auto Layout constraints on those image views; c.) you don't have transforms, changing the `center` property should work.   You get the 'free' effect of having them animated as they move to the new locations.   What happens when you change their `center` properties?

If you're setting the `transform` property to translate them as you drag them around, set the transform to `CGAffineTransformIdentity`.

Comment: I have no transform property as I've just been using touchesBegan and touchesMoved. Changing the center property only works for the last image that was moved on the screen, I'm not sure if theres a way to cycle through every single image that has been moved? Sorry if thats a silly question, I'm pretty new to objective-c.